# Github desktop: Do i lose stashed changes if i commit other changes?

Tags: github, github-desktop

I use Github desktop and I have a few changes stashed but i need to commit other changes as a quick fix before working more on stashed. Restoring stashed and applying the quick fix on top won't work as code changed radically in stashed.

Do i lose stashed changes if i commit other changes before ?

Comment: No, you would not. But for safety, try doing a small demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should not loose what has been stashed.

You can double-check that with [`git stash list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-listltoptionsgt) in command-line, both before and after you have committed your current work.

Comment: @NorbertNagy It is a good occasion to try it: you can launch it from GitHub Desktop: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52496770/6309

Answer (score 1):

Took a leap of faith and committed the quick fix, i didn't loose stashed changes.